# Does sublime text 2 have a plugin that autocompletes folders and files?

Tags: autocomplete, editor, sublimetext2

I'm coming from vim and have a plugin (on vim) that autocompletes folders and files when adding a url in the code...for example

```
background: transparent url(img/glob...)
```

as I'm typing global it highlights it for me...then after pressing enter, a list of all the folders/files in that directory shows up.

Does this exist in sublime? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/BoundInCode/AutoFileName

You can install it via Package Control or clone the repo from github into your ST packages directory (`Preferences > Browse Packages`).

Comment: Thanks for finding this...doesn't seem to work for me very well. On haml files it looks at the base of my hard drive. (I saw a setting to change this but it does nothing). Also doesn't work on SCSS files for me (even though it appears as compatible). Other files it starts in the wrong directory. Hopefully this will be perfected to work like the VIM plugin! :)

Comment: If you find these bugs, could you file the issue through github? I'm actually the maintainer of the repo and unless someone files a report, it's unlikely that the issue will be fixed (especially because I don't do much writing in haml or scss). Thanks!